# Is there some next() iterable for a result of fetchall()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Is there some way to get the next() value of a rows without going through a loop ?

```
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(len(rows)) # 11

# -1, had this worked in Python3, I would've done row = self.cursor.fetchone() instead
print(cursor.rowcount)

r = rows.next() # I want an iterable next()
print(row[1])

# for row in rows:
    # print(row[1])
```

Comment: Isn't that fetchone()?  Otherwise I am confused why you want to fetch all the data then iterate over it.

Comment: I can't use fetchone() as cursor.rowcount is returning -1

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: I meant, I was doing fetchone() in a loop (custom iteration) by tracking cursor.rowcount. cursor.rowcount returns -1 in Python3.

Comment: You iterate over fetchone() till it returns None. You can keep a running count in the loop.  Anyways, looks you figured out what you wanted, and I am still puzzled what the problem was.

Comment: The issue is, I am calculating the total number of rows beforehand : `rows = self.cursor.fetchall(); sql_count = len(self.rows)` - when I do `fetchone()` after this, it's `None `because I already did a `fetchall()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can do :

```
rows_iterator = iter(rows)

row = next(rows_iterator)
print(row[1])
```